# Yolov8 detection value

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, dll, yolo

I want to get the results with two decimal places, such as 0.92, 0.94, etc.

How can I modify the values in this library so that they have two decimal places for example.

`0.9` to `0.92, 0.93, 0.97`

[alpalac 0.9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be35h.png)
become
[alpalac 0.93](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhJMX.png)

the easy and simple way

Comment: it should be "{:.2f}".format()

Comment: @toyotaSupra I already use this format, but the detection value remains 0.9 not 0.92, 0.93

Comment: Can you print one code only?

Comment: @toyotaSupra no, I changed the format to the yolov8 library. however the output I want doesn't change at all.
.
yolo>engine>result.py
.
.
 [label = (f'{name} {conf:.2f}' if conf else name) if labels else None]
 [text = f"{', '.join(f'{names[j] if names else j} {pred_probs[j]:.2f}' for j in top5i)}]